# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.2/$injector/modulerr

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel

always show error in this console
im try this code but not work and show error code "Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] [http://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.2/$injector/modulerr?p0=myapp&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Amodulerr%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.8.2%2F%24injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3DNgTableParams%26p1%3DError%253A%2520%255B%2524injector%253Anomod%255D%2520http%253"](http://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.2/$injector/modulerr?p0=myapp&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Amodulerr%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.8.2%2F%24injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3DNgTableParams%26p1%3DError%253A%2520%255B%2524injector%253Anomod%255D%2520http%253%22)

im try this code :

```
var app = angular.module("myapp", ['datatables'])
app.controller("mainCtrl", ['$scope', '$http', 'NgTableParams', '$interval', '$filter', function($scope, $http, NgTableParams, $interval, $filter) {

$scope.oDistrict = function(trash, order_by) {
    $scope.f.tab = "list";
    $scope.f.trash = trash;
    $scope.tableList = new NgTableParams({}, {
       getData: function($defer, params) {
       var $btn = $('button').button('loading');
       return $http.get("{{ url('mst_district_list') }}", {
           params: {
                page: $scope.tableList.page(),
           }
       }).then(function(response) {
           $btn.button('reset');
           $scope.tableList.total(response.data.data.total);
           return response.data.data.data;
       }, function(error) {
           $btn.button('reset');
           swal('', error.data, 'error');
       });
   }
  });
}
$scope.oDistrict();
}]);
```